# ¿Cómo comunicar Android con el módulo ESP8266 o NodeMCU teniendo oculto su SSID?

Tags: android, android-studio, arduino

Estoy programando Android y necesito comunicarme con un módulo WiFi oculto.

Lo oculto desde Arduino con la instrucción:

`WiFi.softAP(nombre_ssid, contraseña, 1, true)`

Y no encuentro las instrucciones en Android para comunicarme con el módulo oculto.

Estoy probando con la librería WifiManager desde Android Studio.

Gracias.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Encontré que en Android con:

WifiConfiguration

y asignando:

wifiConfig.hiddenSSID = true

Sabiendo el SSID y la contraseña se conecta normalmente.

El problema es que hace visible a ese Punto de Acceso y debe permanecer oculto.